# Compare two list and find names that are in list one and not list two using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, compare

Just wondering if you can help me out.. I am trying to compare two list(txt file) and find strings that are in list A and not in List B and output it to another txt file.. anybody know how to do it using powershell ?

Here is what I have so far:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FolderLists -DifferenceObject $AdUserName -passThru
```

I would like to find all strings that are in $FolderLists and not $AdUserName and possibly output it to another variable. The issue I am having is that it outputs strings that are not in both lists.

Comment: If they're ordered, `FC file1 file2` ought to do the trick. [Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fc.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I assume **$FolderList** and **$AdUserName** are arrays of strings? You don't really need **Compare-Object** to compare arrays. It's as simple as this:

```
$FolderList | ?{$AdUserName -notcontains $_}
```

---

**Compare-Object** is for comparing the specified properties of collections of objects with common properties. You *could* do this with **Compare-Object** if you really want, like this:

```
Compare-Object $FolderList $AdUserName | ?{$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
```

But as you can see, it's overkill for this task.

To output the result to another variable, simply assign it:

```
$AnotherVariable = $FolderList | ?{$AdUserName -notcontains $_}
```