# Compare two lists in Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0

I have just started working on powershell. I have two lists of 132 and 134 records each. They have 85 records in common and I want to get the values which are in list1 but not in list2 in a seperate list say list_out1 and the values which are in list2 but not in list1 in another list say list_out2. I finally want to print list_out1 and list_out2. I tried to do as given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012457/compare-two-list-and-find-names-that-are-in-list-one-and-not-list-two-using-powe) but it is giving me all the values in list1 while trying to print list_out1. Also, I have tried using foreach loop and if condition as below and it is also giving me all the values in list1 to print list_out1.

```
foreach ($i in $list1)
{
   if($list2 -notcontains $i) {
      $i
    }
}
```

I don't know where am I doing wrong. The logic seems to be alright for me. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If the logic is right, then your types are wrong. What kind of records are they? Whatever it is, two things which appear the same are not comparing as the same thing - the typical PowerShell beginner mistake is to want strings or ints, but get PSCustomObjects by doing something like `get-childitem | select name` or `get-childitem | ft name` instead of the more correct `get-childitem | select -expandproperty name`..

Comment: What types are your lists / records? Mind that two object instances are treated as different, even if they might have the same property values.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, How should we deal if there are a slight variations in each record in those lists i mean, one list has value 'ABC' and the other list has 'aB.C'. But I want my function to treat both of same. How do we do data cleaning and perform the required comparision?

Comment: or data something like this
$List1 = 'Hello','World2','Today','FromList1'
$List2 = 'Hello1','World','Todayi','FromList2'
compare $List1 $list2

Comment: @Sree you'll need to be very clear about what "data cleaning" means. Removing numbers and punctuation would be easy enough (`$text -replace '\W')` will do it. and PowerShell ignores uppercase/lowercase when doing comparisons, so that's OK. But what is the rule where `Today` matches `Todayi`? That's going past "data cleaning" and into "spell checker" or "dictionary lookup with probabilities" or "natural language processing magic"...

Answer (score 7):

Using the `Compare-Object` is what you are after. Assuming you do `$List1.Item` or something similar.

```
$MissingGroups = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($List1) -DifferenceObject ($List2) -Property Item | Where-Object{$_.sideIndicator -eq "<="}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?
If you just want to the screen, just remove the Out-File stuff.

> get the values which are in list1 but not in list2 in a seperate list
>   say list_out1

```
$List1 = 'Hello','World','Today','FromList1'
$List2 = 'Hello','World','Today','FromList2'

# get the values which are in list1
ForEach($Item in $List1)
{
    If($List2 -notcontains $Item)
    {$Item | Out-File -FilePath D:\Temp\ListOne.txt -Append} 
} 

# Results in the file

FromList1
```

> and the values which are in list2 but not in list1 in another list say
>   list_out2.

```
ForEach($Item in $List2)
{
    If($List1 -notcontains $Item)
    {$Item | Out-File -FilePath D:\Temp\ListTwo.txt -Append} 
} 

# Results in the file

FromList2
```

Comment: Why don't you just use Compare-Object?

Comment: No disagreement, but the OP wanted to pump to two different files, with individual results, not just a compare. So, just taking the OP at their explicit request.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the proplem you have with the Q&A you linked yourself.

Using the example lists from [postanote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9132707/postanote)'s good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53314991/6811411) and `Compare-Object`

```
## Q:\Test\2018\11\15\SO_53313785.ps1
$List1 = 'Hello','World','Today','FromList1'
$List2 = 'Hello','World','Today','FromList2'
compare $List1 $list2
```

This returns (using alias compare for `Copare-Object` and relying on positional parameter 1 for -ReferenceObject and 2 for -DifferenceObject)

```
InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
FromList2   =>
FromList1   <=
```

You can use the `SideIndicator` to determine to which file the output should be appended.

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $List1 -DifferenceObject $List2 |
    ForEach-Object -Begin {
        Remove-item '.\UniqueToList*.txt'
    } -Process {
       if ($_.SideIndicator -eq '<='){
           Add-Content -Path '.\UniqueToList1.txt' -Value $_.InputObject
       } else {
           Add-Content -Path '.\UniqueToList2.txt' -Value $_.InputObject
       }
    }
```

In case of more complex list objects you might use `Export-Csv` with the `-Append` parameter instead.