# Compare Object Powershell

Tags: powershell, compareobject

I want to compare two objects and get only the different values. I have this code:

```
$a = ("this is blah blah DOG")
$b = ("Dit is blah BLAH dog")
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b
```

with the above code I get the following output:

```
InputObject           SideIndicator
-----------           -------------
Dit is blah BLAH dog  =>           
this is blah blah DOG <=
```

However I want only the different values in both the objects i.e. Dit and this

Answer (score 3):

`Compare-Object`  works on the whole objects and its properties. It will not do lazy string matching. If you wanted that you need to split the string into arrays first

```
$a = "this is blah blah DOG".Split()
$b = "Dit is blah BLAH dog".Split()
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b
```

Beware of potential issues with case sensitivity and use the `-CaseSensitive` as needed.

Answer (score 2):

For this specific example:

```
$a = ("this is blah blah DOG").Split(" ")
$b = ("Dit is blah BLAH dog").Split(" ")
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b
```

Comment: When I do the same for an object that imports values from a csv file I get items in both the objects. Whereas I only want items that are in object1 but not in object2

Comment: Recommend you post a minimum exact repro of what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show what your csv file looks like, so, there's that, but stepping though what you are after.

```
($a = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Documents\file1.txt')
($b = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Documents\file2.txt')
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b

<#
What's in the two files

file1
hello
world



file2
hello
world



InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
file2       =>           
file1       <=           
#>




($a = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Documents\file1.csv')
($b = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Documents\file2.csv')
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b

<#
What's in the two files

Col1,Col2,Col3
file1,hello,world



Col1,Col2,Col3
file2,hello,world



InputObject       SideIndicator
-----------       -------------
file2,hello,world =>           
file1,hello,world <=           
#>



($a = (Get-Content -Path 'D:\Documents\file1.csv' | Select -Skip 1) -split ',')
($b = (Get-Content -Path 'D:\Documents\file2.csv' | Select -Skip 1) -split ',')
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b

<#
file1
hello
world



file2
hello
world




InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
file2       =>           
file1       <=  
#>
```

Lastly, this also sounds eerily like this Q&A

[Compare two lists in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53313785/compare-two-lists-in-powershell/53314991?noredirect=1#comment93511228_53314991)